# Pageviews for Specific URIs within Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-docs

I've started using the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) to simplify some of my weekly reporting. Recently someone on my team has asked about pulling data for specific URIs. I've been through the documentation, I'm not seeing how to accomplish this.

Using a metric of `ga:pageviews` & dimension of `ga:pagePath`, I can get a list of pageviews for all URIs within a profile. The sites I'm working with have thousands of pages so that isn't particularly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is filter out results that don't match a particular pattern. You can use the `filters` option for this:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters

For example, say you have a blog on your site and you only wanted to see results whose URLs started with the text `/articles/`. Here's what that filter would look like (note, this uses a [regular expression](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filterExpressions) to match the pattern):

```
ga:pagePath=~^/articles/
```

And the full query would look like this:

```
metrics:     ga:pageviews
dimensions:  ga:Pathpath
filters:     ga:pagePath=~^/articles/
```

Comment: This is awesome, exactly what I was looking for. I have a follow up question to solidify my understanding. If I want to get reports on both /articles/ and /downloads/, then the easiest way to do this will be to create a profile (view) and add filters to select the specific pages I'm interested in, then call that profile within my spreadsheet?

Comment: It's a little confusing because you can add a filter to a view, and you can also pass the `filters` param to a query (both are called filters). What I've described is passing the `filters` param to a query. If you want to learn more about view filters, here's some information: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162